# Leaving the US while in adjustment for green card

Tags: international-travel

We are expected home (Oz) in March but I'm in adjustment. Can I get an exception to avoid my app being abandon?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clear what you're asking? I have no idea what you mean by Oz, adjustment, app, or where you're from.

Comment: I think you're looking for [expatriates.se].

Comment: @pnuts yeah I agree, I meant for OP to do that, I'm normally trying to edit unclear questions, but here I won't bother ;)

Comment: @Kuba I believe that he means he originally lived in Kansas but a hurricane took him away. HTH.

Comment: "Oz" is slang for Australia. You may notice we pronounce "Aussie" like "Ozzie" - so we call our country "Oz".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to obtain what is called Advanced Parole.

https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/travel-documents/emergency-travel

Make sure you don't have any bars to reentry before leaving because Advance Parole does not guarantee you will be let in, IF it is discovered that you have some ineligibility issues (e.g. you previously overstayed for more than six months).

Since you do not even know what Advance Parole is, I will take it you have very little knowledge of the immigration process and probably have a lawyer handling your adjustment of status petition. I advise you contact him to review BEFORE you leave.

Comment: It doesn't matter how long they have overstayed or how much unlawful presence they may have, as Matter of Arrabally said that leaving the US with Advance Parole does not count as a departure for the purposes of triggering the 9B ban. Only if they currently already have a ban would they maybe have an issue, but in that case, they wouldn't be eligible for Adjustment of Status anyway.